# Parsing the text in a file

Tags: python

I am trying print the contents of a text file using below code,the text file will only contain one line,my current output is as below which
is a list with "\r\n" at the end,I want to the output to be as shown in "EXPECTED OUTPUT" ?

```
branch_textfile =  branch + '.txt'

with open(branch_textfile, 'r') as f: #open the file
    contents = f.readlines() #put the lines to a variable (list).
    #contents = contents.rstrip()
    print contents
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

```
['AU_TEST_PUBLIC_BRANCH.05.01.01.151.005\r\n']
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
AU_TEST_PUBLIC_BRANCH.05.01.01.151.005
```

Comment: The culprit is `readlines()` - it's not the right method for the job here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> x = ['AU_TEST_PUBLIC_BRANCH.05.01.01.151.005\r\n']
>>> print x[0].rstrip()
AU_TEST_PUBLIC_BRANCH.05.01.01.151.005
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

It does that because `f.readlines()` returns an array (or is it a list?)  Either way, you can avoid the brackets with:

```
print contents[0]
```

This works but it only prints the first line of the file.

Comment: A list would be the proper term for python.

Answer (score 1):

Use `contents = f.read().rstrip()` instead of `contents = f.readlines()`. This will read the file into a single string and remove the trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

why did you "#" the .rstrip() out? it is the right command!

you can also put that on the end of the statment like this:

```
with open('file','r') as f:
    data = f.read().strip()
```